# How to populate Grids in bootstrap using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to populate bootstrap grids using jquery but nothing is displayed on the screen.

HTML code:

```
<!--Bootstrap Grids-->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="article">
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" title="News">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=my-api-key',function (json) {
    console.log(json);

    for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
        $('.article News h3').eq(j).html(json.articles[j].title);
        $('.article News p').eq(j).html(json.articles[j].description);
    }

    });
```

I want to display NEWS description in `<p>` tag and NEWS title in `<h3>` tag but nothing is displayed on webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the previous answer, although I will add this as a possibly prefered method to build this structure.

https://jsfiddle.net/xgqzureh/

html:

```
<div class="row" id="articles"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//data that looks similar, use your return 'json' from get
json = {articles: [
    {title: 'art1', description: 'art1 desc'},
    {title: 'art2', description: 'art2 desc'},
    {title: 'art3', description: 'art3 desc'}
]};


//using your set up
for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
    $($('.article h3')[j]).html(json.articles[j].title);
    $($('.article p')[j]).html(json.articles[j].description);
}


//I believe to be a better way to do this
var j, articles = $('#articles');
for(j = 0; j<3 && j < json.articles.length; j += 1){
    $('<div>', {class: 'article'}).append(
        $('<div>', {class: 'col-md-4', title: 'News'})
            .append('<h3>' + json.articles[j].title + '</h3>')
            .append('<p>' + json.articles[j].description + '<p>')
    ).appendTo(articles);
}
```

Comment: My json response looks like this -> http://imgur.com/a/CjvdT So should I use `json = { }` as you mentioned it in first few lines.

Comment: Which is good practice followed by developers is it ok to create elements dynamically or just populate the elements later.

Comment: But if I create elements dynamically will it affect page loading. So if I make elements before and then just populate them using json data would affect less.

Comment: It may, you would have to run tests to compare the speed of selecting elements to creating them. I would guess creating them would be slower, but unless you are running on a crazy old machine, this will not be perceptible to the user. I have created large pages entirely with dynamic loading because I had no choice, and there is no real delay. Any delay you are getting with this is the $.getJSON call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove News while accessing h3 and p , instead of

```
$('.article News h3').eq(j).html(json.articles[j].title);
$('.article News p').eq(j).html(json.articles[j].description);
```

do

```
$('.article h3').eq(j).html(json.articles[j].title);
$('.article p').eq(j).html(json.articles[j].description);
```

Comment: but we are accessing `<h3>` tag which is inside class having title 'News' and this whole thing is inside class article. So shouldn't it be `.article News h3`

Comment: you can't access all attributes directly, only classes are accessed with dot and ids with #